# How to start with cellular automata

Tags: cellular-automata

I have to start working on cellular automaton so can anyone please share the link which may help a beginner to learn the basics.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the following resources as an introduction to Cellular Automata (CA):

- To immediately start playing with different CAs, running their evolution, checking properties – try Wolfram|Alpha. This a computational knowledge engine that turns plane English into computation. [**Type for example “rule 110”**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ca%20rule%20110). This are [**some other examples**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/CellularAutomata.html). Explore!
- A must read is [**“New Kind of Science” book by Stephen Wolfram**](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/toc.html), available online for free (you may need to register once).
- [**The Wolfram Science Summer School**](http://www.wolframscience.com/summerschool/) has great [**free recourses and lectures online**](http://www.wolframscience.com/summerschool/resources/). But I would really recommend [**applying for the actual 3 weeks program**](http://www.wolframscience.com/summerschool/application.cgi). You’ll get hands on experience with doing real research in the CA and related field collaborating with instructors and students.
- The Wolfram Demonstration Project has [**numerous free CA applications**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Cellular%20Automata&limit=20)
- For a deeper read see [**Stephen Wolfram publications**](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/books/ca-reprint/)
- MathWorld has good intro articles: [**Elementary Cellular Automaton**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryCellularAutomaton.html) and [**Cellular Automaton**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CellularAutomaton.html)
- And of course the best tool would be [**Mathematica**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) with built-in [**CellularAutomaton**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellularAutomaton.html) function and a lot of related research functionality. You can download [**free trial version**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/) or check if your school has licence.

P.S. This is sample CA Mathematica code showing how easy and compact programming structures look in that language:

```
Image3D /@ CellularAutomaton[{14, {2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{{{1}}}, 0}, {{3, 10}}]
```

[image]

```
Table[ArrayPlot[Mean[
   CellularAutomaton[{i, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{{1}}, 0}, 30]],], 
{i, 2, 20, 4}]
```

[image]